# Calls to SpreadsheetApp are very slow

Tags: google-apps-script

I have huge problems with speed of getting spreadsheet data.

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById([0AhKzbVoTxxxxxxRdDlOVC1zazFNNVE]) [33.219 seconds]
Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([bellijst]) [132.543 seconds]
```

// then there is a user doing some work, while the values are in the screen, then the user submits a form, and there we go on:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById([0AhKxxxxxxRG9TalVRdDlOVC1zazFNNVE]) [37.516 seconds]
Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([bellijst]) [0.043 seconds]
ScriptProperties.getProperty([ID]) [0.017 seconds]
Sheet.getLastRow() [0.023 seconds]
Sheet.getRange([1, 2, 258]) [0.023 seconds]
Range.getValues() [0.031 seconds]
```

132 seconds is very much, why is this happening?

There are just 1 or 2 people working in these sheets, and the script is called by max 3 people at same time...

Answer (score 0):

What's the value in `['Bellijst']`?

Normally you just call the spreadsheet by name, like so:

```
Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheetName')
```

As you may read in the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#getSheetByName)

Comment: The sheetname is 'bellijst'. It's not an array, for some reason the "" are gone. But that part is not slow, the openById is very slow.